# save form using the keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

i have form with some fields and a save button.  On clicking save all the records are inserted into the table. Now i want to add this data throuth keyboard shortcut. i.e. if i enter (shift+V) capital v then the record has to be inserted. Is it possible? anybody can help me plz?

thanks.

Comment: What if someone wants to type a capital V?

Comment: This is done with Javascript. PHP does not care how you submit HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript here.

If to assume that your save button is declared as `<button type=submit>Save</button>` then it is enough to declare `accesskey` attribute on it like this:

```
<button type="submit" accesskey="v">Save</button>
```

This way on Windows you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to activate that button (do its click action).
On Mac it will be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: @user828122: If it's working you might consider accepting this answer by checking the tick.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the onkeydown and onkeyup method to the document to track when buttons are pressed and when they are released.

```
var ctrl=false;
var shft=false;

function onkd(e){
  //check event key
  ctrl=true;
  //are all buttons pressed?
      //kick off

}
document.onkeydown = onkd;

function onku(e){
   //check event key
   ctrl=false;

}
document.onkeyup = onku;
```